# Maintaining EC2 Servers with Chef Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, autoscaling

I have a hosted chef account working with AWS EC2 instances.

The instances can connect to hosted chef by way of chef-client and run the inital
run_list that is presetly a role called servers.  Everything runs and installs 
correctly on initial provision.

I should also mention I have autoscaling on ec2 instances that increses the amount of instances 
provisioned on an 'as needed' basis and this works fine.

I found one talk that sort of makes sense but seems a bit more involved.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHub6E4DNvg

My questions are around how to maintain the servers after initial provisioning.  First, if I have an update to my role to include more cookbooks or configuration, and how would I push this out to say X amount servers in a simple way.

Second, how would chef server know if a node has failed and notify the admin?

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite vast question ...

For the easy one: failing node => the solution is to use report handlers see the doc [here](http://docs.chef.io/handlers.html)

For the keep in desired state, the idea is to have chef run periodically on the nodes, so it keep enforcing the conf defined in cookbooks, any change will be updated accordingly. (that's the way chef has been concepted).

If you want more control on which server run when you can:

1. use the push-jobs addon (commercial addon, not free)
2. use some orchestration tool (I personnaly use rundeck for adhoc runs in addition to periodic runs).

There's a lot of way to do this and which one to use is a question of preference and environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use knife to run a chef-client based on a certain criteria:

```
knife ssh 'role:somerole' 'chef-client' -x username -P password
```

Here is chef's documentation: https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html